# How to fix the expanded height of umano slidingpanellayout

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

I am trying to fix the expanded height of the sliding panel. What I want is that the sliding panel layout can be expanded only to 40 or 50% of screen height. I tried adding umanoAnchorPoint attribute with value 0.4 but the view can still be dragged to full screen.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the sliding listener like this:

```
slidingUpPanelLayout.addPanelSlideListener(new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelStateChanged(View panel, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState previousState, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState newState) {
                if(newState == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED) slidingUpPanelLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED);
            }
        });
```

or maybe:

```
slidingUpPanelLayout.addPanelSlideListener(new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
                if(slideOffset > desiredOffset) slidingUpPanelLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelStateChanged(View panel, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState previousState, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState newState) {

            }
        });
```